# JQuery: how to access multiple css classes using .attr()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following:

```
<div id="unique" class="myclass xyz_345">...</div>
```

**Question**: How do I access what # is after `xyz_`, given that I have 2 css classes being applied to it? (In the example above, it would be the number 345).

I've tried the following, but it does work:

```
var num_after_xyz = $('unique').attr("class").substring(4);
```

Comment: Can you say what you mean by "that doesn't work"? What does the above result in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var num_after_xyz = $('#unique').attr("class").match(/^.*_(\d+).*/);
alert(num_after_xyz[1]);
```

This regular expression should work.

It looks for anything, followed by _ and some digits, followed by anything.

Comment: I used:  $('#unique').attr("class").match(/^.*_(\d+).*/)[1]; and that works.

Comment: nice, a lot more concise than mine ;p you could wrap this in a simple plugin to allow searching for the number after a specific prefix (in case you have multiple possible class prefixes)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that

```
var myString = $("#unique").attr("class")
```

is going to return "abc xyz_345".  So then you could split that string on space:

```
var mySplitResult = myString.split(" ");
```

and iterate through the resulting array looking for something that starts with "xyz_" - and then taking the substring of that element.

```
var s;
for (s in mySplitResult){
     if(s.substring(0,4) == "xyz_"){
          var numberAfterXYZ = s.substring(4);
     }
}
```

Comment: So I tried, var num_after_xyz = $('unique').attr("class").split(" ").substring(4); and that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: numAfterXyz = $('unique').attr("class").split(" ").substring(4);

Comment: Wait no.  Split is going to return an array.  You'll need to look through each element in that array for "xyz_" before taking the substring of that particular element.

Comment: You should see what `$('unique').attr("class")` returns, and work from there

Comment: `split` returns an array and not an object and `for (… in …)` is suitable for arrays. Use `for (…;…;…)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines:

```
jQuery.fn.getClassNumber = function(classPrefix){
    var classes = this.attr('class').split(" ");
    jQuery.each(classes, function(i){
        if (classes[i].substring(0,classPrefix.length-1)==classPrefix){
            return classes[i].substring(classPrefix.length-1);
            }
        });
    return false;
    }
```

Then to get the number after the class prefix:

```
$('element').getClassNumber('xyz_');
```

I think this will work but I haven't tested it, give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a little plugin for this:

```
//
// ReplaceClass
//
// @param   regexp|substr       The old classname you are looking for
// @param   newSubStr|function  The new classname
// @see     https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
// @depends jQuery
// @author  @abernier
//
(function($) {
    $.fn.replaceClass = function(oldClass, newClass){
        return this.each(function(i, el){
            $(el).attr('class', function(index, attr){
                return attr.replace(oldClass, newClass);
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

eg:

```
$('<div class="foo bar"></div>').replaceClass('foo', 'bar');
# => [div.bar.bar]
```

or with regexp:

```
$('<div class="foo-25 bar"></div>').replaceClass(/foo-[0-9]{2}/, 'foo-100');
# => [div.foo-100.bar]
```